# Pasting a string in a loop

Tags: r, string, loops

I am writing some code for a loop and I want to paste a string in the loop.  However, for some reason the command "paste" does not seems to work:

A simple example:

```
### Creating some variables
test1<-c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
test2<-c(4,6,7,2,5,3,6,2,7,1)
test3<-c(3,5,6,7,7,7,7,3,5,3)

### An example of a loop
for (i in 1:2)
{
   name<-paste("test",i,sep="")
   fit <- lm(name~test2+test3)
}
```

I don't understand why this works:

```
fit <- lm(test1~test2+test3)
```

But this doesn't:

```
fit <- lm(name~test2+test3)
```

even though paste is equal to test1.

Any help would be much appreciated.  Ideally I would like to use a loop rather than apply.

Comment: `test1` is the actual object while `name` is the name of it (`"test1"`)...

Comment: thanks so how can I refer to the actual object in the loop?

Comment: Why your loop is running from 1:2, are you trying to fit `lm(test2~test2+test3)` model too?

Comment: It's just an example.  My code is actually more complicated than this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, put your vectors in a data.frame. Second, you don't need a loop in this example.

```
DF <- data.frame(test1,
                 test2,
                 test3)

fits <- lm(do.call(cbind, DF[, 1:2]) ~ test2 + test3, data=DF)
#Coefficients:
#                  test1       test2     
#(Intercept)   7.655e+00   1.123e-15
#test2        -3.669e-01   1.000e+00
#test3        -1.089e-01   3.594e-17
```

Note that the result for `test2` differs from `lm(test2 ~ test2 + test3)` because the response variable on the RHS is not removed.

Comment: +1 as I did not know that you can run `lm` on a matrix like response, though it is clearly stated in the help (I should read the help files from functions I am using everyday ;))

Answer (score 3):

`get` returns the value of a named object:

```
fit2 <- lm(get(name)~test2+test3)
```